# Слетают стили плагина jQuery при обновлении через Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, jsp

Всем привет!

Есть неприятный трабл с обновлением части HTML страницы (JSP) через ajax.
Контейнер, который обновляется, содержит 3 комбобокса (добавляются новые блоки с комбобоксами ниже). jQuery-Плагин стилизует `<select>` под комбобокс, выпадающий и с мультивыбором. Сам плагин сделан так, что он добавляет кнопку и ставит её на место select'а, а сам select скрывает. Ещё добавляет блок `<div>` в конце HTML, который отображается как выпадающее меню под этой кнопкой.

Навешивается плагин в jQuery вот так: `$('select').multiselect(){[тут настройки]}`. При обновлении через ajax все классы и стили, добавленные плагином, слетают.

Подскажите, как решить проблему?

Есть ещё такой момент, что ajax используется встроеный (в тег JSP). AjaxStop() почему-то не срабатывает (`ajaxSetup{ global:true }`). Если поместить скрипт навешивания плагина в контейнер, который ajax'ом обновляется, - все работает. Но хотелось бы как-то поцивилизованнее, не разбрасывая скрипты по HTML.

Буду рад любым предложениям.

**Обновление**

Это даже виджет. Он довольно длинный, но есть ссылка на gitHub:
https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/blob/master/src/jquery.multiselect.js

Comment: Надо бы плагин посмотреть

Comment: Я ошибся, это даже виджет. Он довольно длинный, но есть ссылка на gitHub. https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/blob/master/src/jquery.multiselect.js